# What was Junior-G's superpower?

Tags: character, junior-g

In [*Junior-G*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junior_G), I just remember the titular character used to do "Jee, Jam, Jamni, Boom" (Boom with hands crossed) and his costume used to be changed in a snap.

But, what were his superpowers?